# Javascript update items in array without overriding the array, update only the object items

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, merge

I have a problem with updating items in a array.

I receive from mongodb via change streams, updated collection items.
These object needs to be merged with a existing object that include arrays.

The following examples illustrates what the core problem is (Minimalized):

```js
const data = {
    name: "Name1",
    desc: "Description",
    values: [{
        key: "key1",
        value: null,
        desc: "desc 1"
    }, {
        key: "key2",
        value: true,
        desc: "desc 2"
    }]
};

// log original data
console.log(data);


// update object coems from mongodb via change stream
const update = {
    desc: "New Description",
    values: [{
        key: "key1",
        value: true
    }, {
        key: "key2",
        value: false
    }]
};

// update mechanism
Object.assign(data, update);

// display updated data
console.log(data);
```

The problem with `Object.assign` is, the `.values` array from the original data is override and not merged.

I need a function that merges every object, no matter if the object is inside a array or not. This must work recursive, and no matter how nested.

I came up with a function that looks like this:
*merge.js*

```js
function merge(target, source) {

    let loop = (dst, src) => {
        if (src instanceof Object) {

            Object.keys(src).forEach((key) => {
                if (src[key] instanceof Array) {

                    dst[key] = src[key].map((item, i) => {
                        return Object.assign(dst[key][i], item);
                    });

                } else if (src[key] instanceof Object) {

                    loop(dst[key], src[key]);

                } else {

                    dst[key] = src[key];

                }
            });

        } else {

            throw new TypeError(`src is not a instance of object`)

        }
    };

    loop(target, source);

}
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```js
const util = require("util");
const _merge = require("./merge.js");

const data = {
name: "Name1",
desc: "Description",
config: {
    foo: "bar"
},
values: [{
    key: "key1",
    value: null,
    desc: "desc 1",
    services: [{
        name: "http",
        port: 80,
        connections: []
    }]
}, {
    key: "key2",
    value: true,
    desc: "desc 2",
    services: [
        {
            name: "http",
            port: 80,
            connections: []
        }, {
            name: "ws",
            port: 8080,
            connections: []
        }
    ]
}]
};

// log original data
console.log(data);


// update object coems from mongodb via change stream
const update = {
desc: "New Description",
config: {
    foo: "baz"
},
values: [{
    key: "key1",
    value: true,
    desc: "new Descipriotn",
}, {
    key: "key2",
    value: false,
    services: [{
        name: "https",
        port: 443
    }, {
        name: "ws",
        port: 8433
    }]
}]
};

// update mechanism
//Object.assign(data, update);
_merge(data, update);

// display updated data
console.log(util.inspect(data, false, 10, true));
```

The problem with the merge function is, that when a property exists inside the original object inside a arrays like `connection`, this does not exists in the update target.

Output:

```js
{
  name: 'Name1',
  desc: 'New Description',
  config: { foo: 'baz' },
  values: [
    {
      key: 'key1',
      value: true,
      desc: 'new Descipriotn',
      services: [ { name: 'http', port: 80, connections: [] } ]
    },
    {
      key: 'key2',
      value: false,
      desc: 'desc 2',
      services: [ { name: 'https', port: 443 }, { name: 'ws', port: 8433 } ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, in the services arrays, the "connections" property is missing.
What do i need to change in my merge function to keep all property's from the original target object, but also merge everything recursive from the update data?

---

EDIT: When is swap in the merge.js this part:

```js
   
dst[key] = src[key].map((item, i) => {
    return Object.assign(dst[key][i], item);
});
```

with:

```js
src[key].forEach((item, i) => {
    loop(dst[key][i], item);
});
```

i get the output i want:

```js
{
  name: 'Name1',
  desc: 'New Description',
  config: { foo: 'baz' },
  values: [
    {
      key: 'key1',
      value: true,
      desc: 'new Descipriotn',
      services: [ { name: 'http', port: 80, connections: [] } ]
    },
    {
      key: 'key2',
      value: false,
      desc: 'desc 2',
      services: [
        { name: 'https', port: 443, connections: [] },
        { name: 'ws', port: 8433, connections: [] }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT/Bug found:

With the given input (Array full of strings added) it produces a weird output and convert the string to a object.

```js
const update = {
    desc: "New Description",
    config: {
        foo: "baz"
    },
    values: [{
        key: "key1",
        value: true,
        desc: "new Descipriotn",
    }, {
        key: "key2",
        value: false,
        services: [{
            name: "https",
            port: 443
        }, {
            name: "ws",
            port: 8433
        }]
    }],
    labels: [
        "manufacturer=shelly",
        "foo=bar",
        "foo=baz"
    ]
};
```

Output:

```js
{
  name: 'Name1',
  desc: 'New Description',
  config: { foo: 'baz' },
  values: [
    {
      key: 'key1',
      value: true,
      desc: 'new Descipriotn',
      services: [Array]
    },
    { key: 'key2', value: false, desc: 'desc 2', services: [Array] }
  ],
  labels: [
    {
      '0': 'm',
      '1': 'a',
      '2': 'n',
      '3': 'u',
      '4': 'f',
      '5': 'a',
      '6': 'c',
      '7': 't',
      '8': 'u',
      '9': 'r',
      '10': 'e',
      '11': 'r',
      '12': '=',
      '13': 's',
      '14': 'h',
      '15': 'e',
      '16': 'l',
      '17': 'l',
      '18': 'y'
    },
    {
      '0': 'f',
      '1': 'o',
      '2': 'o',
      '3': '=',
      '4': 'b',
      '5': 'a',
      '6': 'r'
    },
    {
      '0': 'f',
      '1': 'o',
      '2': 'o',
      '3': '=',
      '4': 'b',
      '5': 'a',
      '6': 'z'
    }
  ]
}
```

It should keep the string of arrays and do not mess with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. It loops through each property of the object and determines how to merge it. If the current property is an array, it will map that array into an array of merged objects by index. If it's an object, it will recursively call the merge function to return the merged object, and if it's a non-object we can simply treat it like a normal `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`, where the value from obj2 overrides the value from obj1.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```js
const data = {
name: "Name1",
desc: "Description",
config: {
    foo: "bar"
},
values: [{
    key: "key1",
    value: null,
    desc: "desc 1",
    services: [{
        name: "http",
        port: 80,
        connections: []
    }]
}, {
    key: "key2",
    value: true,
    desc: "desc 2",
    services: [
        {
            name: "http",
            port: 80,
            connections: []
        }, {
            name: "ws",
            port: 8080,
            connections: []
        }
    ]
}]
};


// update object coems from mongodb via change stream
const update = {
desc: "New Description",
config: {
    foo: "baz"
},
values: [{
    key: "key1",
    value: true,
    desc: "new Descipriotn",
}, {
    key: "key2",
    value: false,
    services: [{
        name: "https",
        port: 443
    }, {
        name: "ws",
        port: 8433
    }]
}]
};

function mergeObjs (sourceObj, updateObj) {
  return Object.entries(updateObj).reduce((res, [currKey, currValue]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(currValue)) {
      let sourceArray = sourceObj[currKey] || [];
      res[currKey] = currValue.map((valObj, index) => {
        // this is simply merging on index, but if you wanted a "smarter" merge, you could look up
        // the sourceObj by a specific key with sourceArray.find(...)
        return mergeObjs(sourceArray[index] || {}, valObj)
      });
    } else if (typeof currValue === 'object' && currValue !== null) {
      res[currKey] = mergeObjs(sourceObj[currKey] || {}, currValue)
    } else {
      res[currKey] = currValue;
    }
    return res;
  }, sourceObj);
}

console.log(mergeObjs(data, update));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The function does not work 100% how i thought, if arrays & objects are deeper tested, some information gets lost. For my first use case but absolutely perfect! Can you please elaborate for me how you have written this function? I want too try to better understand recursive functions, `Object.entries` & `Array.reduce` are not the problem, im more interested what was your "train of thought" while you have written this function. Recursive functions are a nightmare for me, and i want to improve my self.

Comment: @Marc In short, it's really just thinking through how you want to merge each type of property. I started with arrays since I knew that was the problem - we didn't want to overwrite the entire array, or each entire object in the array, so instead we populate an array with merged objects. Next case was handling objects, in that case, I just want to recursively call because that's the purpose of the mergeObjs function. Lastly, any non-array and non-object property just gets written with the new value and bubbles back up to the previous call stack. Hard to explain more than that in these comments

Comment: thats enough explanation for me. Thank you :) I think the rest comes with practice. Do you have any docs or books your can recommend for recursion?

Comment: @Marc Kyle Simpson's [Functional-Light-JS Chapter 8](https://github.com/getify/Functional-Light-JS/blob/master/manuscript/ch8.md) has a pretty thorough explanation of different types of recursion and how they can be used beyond the academic "fibonacci sequence" exercise. I'd read through that a few times and other than that it just comes with a lot of practice and tinkering around with it. Eventually it clicks and is pretty intuitive, even though it may seem like black magic at first lol

Comment: I found a bug in the function. It converts a array of strings into a array of objects. Please see the section "EDIT/Bug found" in my edited question.